# How check if new function is working on prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm new in prestashop and there is a thing that i don't understand.

I need to add a function that get a file CSV and stock all in a array.
This function will be added in a exixsting Class in this path  "/modules/sdevmanomano/classes/MyClass.php"
Now i have to test the new function, and it the end of the class (out of the {}), i did a var_dump of my object.method().
When i go at the adress of file in my browser, i get nothing. (i m in the correct path). Why?
Exemple:

```
/modules/sdevmanomano/classes/MyClass.php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/OtherClass.php');

class MyClass
{
...
//Before execute the code i want check if he has open correctly the CSV in tmpName
    private function getDeliveryPrices(){
        $tmpName = fopen(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/prices/prezzi_spedizione_francia.csv', 'r');
        if ($tmpName){
           $csvAsArray = 'ok';
        } else {
            $csvAsArray = 'errore';
        }

        return $csvAsArray;
    }
}
// end of class
$test = new MyClass();

$res = $test->getDeliveryPrice();
var_dump($res);
```

Normally at this point, at the adresse https:/.../modules/sdevmanomano/classes/MyClass.php  i have to see my dump, but didn' happen. Why ?

Comment: Well if you don't use the autoloader and directly go to the file then `_PS_VERSION_` won't be defined and trigger the `exit`

Comment: sorry for my question, how can i use autloader in this case ?

Comment: Is your class used outside a PrestaShop admin session within the module, or is it to be launched stand_alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you would want to use your php script outside a PrestaShop session within the module context, here is how you could require the PrestaShop configuration when on a stand-alone php script:

```php
// /modules/sdevmanomano/classes/MyClass.php

/*
 * Require the PrestaShop configuration
 * relative to the location of this script
 */
reqire_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '../../../config/config.inc.php';

// Then you have access to _PS_VERSION_
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}
```